# How to add a background image to header content?

Tags: magento2.2, header, luma-theme

It's been last 42 hours i am trying to get a background image to header content on luma! [magento 2]
but nothing getting accurately!! 
how do i add a background image to header content on magento luma!!? and make it **sticky** or **fixed on top**!!!
can anybody give me just proper guide through this problem i'm stuck with? 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to fix full header with Default welcome msg etc? or only the section you are showing in screenshot?

Comment: do have both solution?

Comment: yeah!! what about that full one and must have to be sticky!

Comment: @SukumarGorai Dada How can i find you on facebook? so that i could ask you some favour!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying this on default luma theme then you can try the below css:

```
.page-wrapper .page-header{position: fixed; width: 100%; background: #fff; z-index: 999;}
.page-wrapper .nav-sections{margin-top:131px;}
```

Add this css to your css file or any less file. Flush the cache. And run any required commands if needed.

Comment: what about background image on it?

Comment: Sticky is working?

Comment: After Deploying Customised Luma Theme!!! Css / layout none of them are working!!! :(

Comment: Check file permissions

Comment: static content working fine!!! Thanks Man!!!

Comment: but it removes my categories @Sukumar Gorai

Comment: No it should not remove any categories. As it is a css fixing. You can check the height of the header and set that height value to margin-top .page-wrapper .nav-sections{margin-top:131px;}

Comment: ohhh!! the margin height making the categories hidden !!! :v Thanks Lot Man!!

Comment: how do i add a background image with that code?

Comment: Dada Can we just talk??? if you don't mind!!

Comment: Yes sure. Do you want to add backgroud image? How it should be look like. Please share a screenshot.

Comment: Okay Dada, As A Choto Bhai I was desperately seeking for someone like you who can help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have tried, 
Deploy, 
cache, 
di:compile, 
reindex

But still not working!!!! :'(

Comment: remove `pub/static` and deploy again but also specify your locale.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was wanting this tent as header background will flot on top while scrolling !! so that it feels like when i scroll, page goes under that tent!!

Comment: @Sukumar Dada !!